# Convex hull of the union of two parameterized curves in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: convex-geometry

My goal is to find a way to calculate the convex hull of the union of some parameterized curves.

For instance, I had to calculate the convex hull of  $A=\{(-4k,k^2+2,2k^2-2k)|k\ge 2\}\cup \{(k,k^2/4-1,-k^2/4-k)|k\le -2\}$. I am aware with the Fenchel-Bunt theorem, so I just have to consider every (closed) triangles made by $a,b,c\in A$. I wanted to do this by hand, but it was very complicated to do. My question is : is there a way to calculate this convex hull?

I do not believe that this is a research-level question, but I didn't get any comments or answers in math.stackexchange.

Comment: I gave a partial answer at MSE. Here is the original question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1166518/166535

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate"? In what terms do you want the result?

Comment: Anything geometrically special about the two curves? What kind of an answer do you expect (qualitatively)?

Comment: I want to calculate the minimum value of $z$ when $x,y$ is given, and while $(x,y,z)\in\mathrm{con}(A)$.

Comment: I am working on specific families of inequalities, and one of my problems state that every inequality, understood geoemetrically, are in the convex hull of two specific curves. One of the simplest case is this. These curves are algebraically special : they are not random, but I cannot find a significant geometrical meaning.

Comment: What is the meaning of "$l\le -2$"? Did you mean $k$ rather than $l$?

Comment: Houtarou, thank you for your comment/answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might see if this paper helps:

> Ranestad, Kristian, and Bernd Sturmfels. "On the convex hull of a space curve." arXiv:0912.2986 (2009). ([arXiv abstract link](http://arxiv.org/abs/0912.2986))

---

[image: CurveHull]

     
<sup>The yellow surface is $z - 4x^3 + 3x = 0$.
The green surface has degree $16$.
The pink triangle is planar.</sup>


     

<sup>(Image due to  Frank Sottile,
Philip Rostalski.)</sup>

---

If an approximate hull would suffice, it is "easy" to compute the 3D convex hull
of many points along your curves.
Here is a crude attempt on your two curves $A$:

---

[image: CurveHull]

---

Comment: @Houtarou: Could you describe your "different way"?

Comment: I viewed this set in R3 as a set of inequalities.(By some calculation I have done before) In this perspective,  finding out the minimum of z was quite easy to do.